# Validating multiple dates to the same hour timepoint

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with several subjects with hour timepoints (0.02,24.02,48.02 etc) for each record per subject.

Each record has 4 dates with a single record assigned to each timepoint (0.02= 28AUG2019, 24.02= 29AUG2019 etc).

The date should be the same for each hour *timepoint*.

What sas function could I use to validate that the dates for each record assigned to each hour *timepoint* is the same for each subject ?

Would the IFC/IFN function work in this scenario?

[Sample data for one subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76W9D.png)

Comment: Hopefully this is clearer

Answer (score 0):

For the case of a data set with variables `time1-time4` and `date1-date4` I see at least two interpretations of the question.

**One**

Are the date values all the same across the record?

The date values can be arrayed and examined in a loop for a change from one index to the previous.

```
data have;
  format time1-time4 6.2 date1-date4 date9.;
  informat date1-date4 date9.;
  input time1-time4 date1-date4;
datalines;
0.02 24.02 48.02 72.02 28AUG2019 29AUG2019 28AUG2019 28AUG2019
1.02 34.02 58.02 82.02 01SEP2019 01SEP2019 01SEP2019 01SEP2019
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array dates date1-date4;

  do index=2 to dim(dates);
    if dates(index) ne dates(index-1) then at_least_one_date_different_flag = 1;
  end;

  drop index;
run;
```

**Two**

> The date should be the same for each hour *timepoint*.

This could be construed to mean looking **down** the data set, for each distinct value of time in any of the `time1-time4` variables the corresponding date values in the `date1-date4` must be also be distinct.

```
row 1: 1 2 3 4 A B C D
row 2: 1 2 3 5 A B C D
row 3: 1 3 5 2 A X D B
```

Looking down you have `3:C, 3:C, 3:X` which would be different (`3` has `C's` and `X's`)

If this is the case, please update the question with more sample data of what you *have* and *want*.

Comment: I've provided sample data in it's source format. i need to do it without using datalines as it is a large dataset or by referencing/hardcoding dates into the program